# Having issues with numbers being printed

Tags: python, string, random, int, coin-flipping

I'm working on a coinflip game which adds your inputed value to your balance

Snippets of code from earlier:

```
deposit = input("Enter how much to deposit")

money = file1.read()

resultmonecoin = int(money)-int(deposit)
```

Main code that test if you got Tails right

```
elif flipresults == "Tails":
                    print("You flip the coin")
                    time.sleep(2)
                    print("It's tails")
                    if HORT.upper() == "T" or "t":
                        wincoin = int(deposit)*2
                        print("You won",wincoin)
                        howmuchwin = wincoin+money
                        print("Total:",int(howmuchwin))
                    else:
                        print("You lost that one. You now have",resultmonecoin)
                        game()
                else:
                    print("This input wasn't understood!")
                    flip()
```

Note:
money variable is something like `500` or `200`

Issue:

[H]eads or [T]ails T

You flip the coin

It's tails

You won 468

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\yeet\Desktop\Casino.py", line 40, in flip
    howmuchwin = wincoin+money
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str
```

Comment: "money variable is something like 500 or 200". Is it `500`, or is it `"500"`? Very important distinction.

Comment: `500` without any quotes

Comment: If you're saying "when I do `print(money)`, it displays `500`, that doesn't really answer my question. Both `500` and `"500"` look like `500` when you print them.

Comment: So money is stored in a TXT file and I  type: money = file1.read()  In the txt file there is nothing other than the number `500` as displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says you can't concatenate a string and an integer together. Looks like your file is reading in a string so you need to cast it as an integer like this `int(money)` to be able to perform maths operations

Comment: Thanks, I looked into it a little, turns out everything broke because teh filed wasn't being read as an integer!